# How to flow these boxes dynamically in CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to achieve something like the image below. Basically it will be header 80px, main container containing a grid which will have flexboxes inside and then a footer. I want the flexboxes to dynamically fit and flow to the next row when resized, preferably without the help of media query.

[image]

But I'm facing several problems with this:

1. First I need the flexboxes to have a certain height when seen in the desktop mode and not reach until the footer.
2. I want the viewport to stay fixed in desktop mode as well.
3. In tablet and mobile version, the flexbox contents are overflowing. Something is wrong with the svg icons as well.
   4.The grid is not flowing as it should.

So in one line: **I want the flexboxes to flow in the next row automatically depending on the device size using CSS Grid, without breaking.**

I'm attaching the code below. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.menu');
  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('burgerNav-active');
    burger.classList.toggle('switch');
  });
}

navSlide();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
}

.master-container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.padding-container {
  padding: 0 40px;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgb(231, 231, 231);
}

.nav-menuList {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  /*gap: 4rem; can't use this here for some reason*/
}

.nav-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.menu-link:link,
.menu-link:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
}

.burger div {
  width: 2.2rem;
  height: 0.2rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

main {
  text-align: center;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px - 50px);
  /*viewport - header -footer*/
}

.page-heading {
  width: 50%;
}

.card-main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(35rem, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2.4rem;
  padding-top: 4rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.card-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  /*gap: 2.4rem; Can't use this here for some reason*/
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 6.4rem 4rem 4rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  min-height: 70%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 6.4rem;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  width: 75%;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 3.9rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
}

.box-description {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 2.8rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.secondary-btn {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 2.8rem;
  color: blue;
}

footer {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  height: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.7rem;
    line-height: 3.6rem;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 0vh;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: -4px 4px 48px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
    border-radius: 0 0 1.2rem 1.2rem;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-menuList {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}

.burgerNav-active {
  height: 40vh;
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch .burger-line1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-0px, 5px);
}

.switch .burger-line2 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0px, -5px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1240px) {
  h3 {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
  }
  .box-description {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  .secondary-btn {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="master-container padding-container">
  <!--Navigation starts here-->
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M0 4C0 1.79086 1.79086 0 4 0H28C30.2091 0 32 1.79086 32 4V28C32 30.2091 30.2091 32 28 32H4C1.7908
  text-align: center;6 32 0 30.2091 0 28V4Z" fill="black" />
          </svg>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul class="nav-menuList">
          <li class="nav-list"><a class="menu-link" href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-list"><a class="menu-link" href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-list"><a class="menu-link" href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="burger">
        <div class="burger-line1"></div>
        <div class="burger-line2"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!--Navigation ends here-->
  <main>
    <section class="page-heading">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="card-main">
      <div class="card-box">
        <div class="icons">
          <svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M24 4C21.3736 4 18.7728 4.51732 16.3463 5.52241C13.9198 6.5275 11.715 8.00069 9.85786 9.85786C6.10714 13.6086 4 18.6957 4 24C4 29.3043 6.10714 34.3914 9.85786 38.1421C11.715 39.9993 13.9198 41.4725 16.3463 42.4776C18.7728 43.4827 21.3736 44 24 44C29.3043 44 34.3914 41.8929 38.1421 38.1421C41.8929 34.3914 44 29.3043 44 24C44 21.3736 43.4827 18.7728 42.4776 16.3463C41.4725 13.9198 39.9993 11.715 38.1421 9.85786C36.285 8.00069 34.0802 6.5275 31.6537 5.52241C29.2272 4.51732 26.6264 4 24 4V4ZM14.14 36.56C15 34.76 20.24 33 24 33C27.76 33 33 34.76 33.86 36.56C31.0588 38.7921 27.5817 40.0051 24 40C20.28 40 16.86 38.72 14.14 36.56ZM36.72 33.66C33.86 30.18 26.92 29 24 29C21.08 29 14.14 30.18 11.28 33.66C9.15237 30.8892 7.99933 27.4934 8 24C8 15.18 15.18 8 24 8C32.82 8 40 15.18 40 24C40 27.64 38.76 31 36.72 33.66V33.66ZM24 12C20.12 12 17 15.12 17 19C17 22.88 20.12 26 24 26C27.88 26 31 22.88 31 19C31 15.12 27.88 12 24 12ZM24 22C23.2044 22 22.4413 21.6839 21.
  text-align: center;8787 21.1213C21.3161 20.5587 21 19.7956 21 19C21 18.2044 21.3161 17.4413 21.8787 16.8787C22.4413 16.3161 23.2044 16 24 16C24.7956 16 25.5587 16.3161 26.1213 16.8787C26.6839 17.4413 27 18.2044 27 19C27 19.7956 26.6839 20.5587 26.1213 21.1213C25.5587 21.6839 24.7956 22 24 22Z" fill="black" />
          </svg>

        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>Lorem and Ipsum</h3>
          <p class="box-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button-group">
          <a class="secondary-btn" href="#">See all</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-box">
        <div class="icons">
          <svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M24 4C21.3736 4 18.7728 4.51732 16.3463 5.52241C13.9198 6.5275 11.715 8.00069 9.85786 9.85786C6.10714 13.6086 4 18.6957 4 24C4 29.3043 6.10714 34.3914 9.85786 38.1421C11.715 39.9993 13.9198 41.4725 16.3463 42.4776C18.7728 43.4827 21.3736 44 24 44C29.3043 44 34.3914 41.8929 38.1421 38.1421C41.8929 34.3914 44 29.3043 44 24C44 21.3736 43.4827 18.7728 42.4776 16.3463C41.4725 13.9198 39.9993 11.715 38.1421 9.85786C36.285 8.00069 34.0802 6.5275 31.6537 5.52241C29.2272 4.51732 26.6264 4 24 4V4ZM14.14 36.56C15 34.76 20.24 33 24 33C27.76 33 33 34.76 33.86 36.56C31.0588 38.7921 27.5817 40.0051 24 40C20.28 40 16.86 38.72 14.14 36.56ZM36.72 33.66C33.86 30.18 26.92 29 24 29C21.08 29 14.14 30.18 11.28 33.66C9.15237 30.8892 7.99933 27.4934 8 24C8 15.18 15.18 8 24 8C32.82 8 40 15.18 40 24C40 27.64 38.76 31 36.72 33.66V33.66ZM24 12C20.12 12 17 15.12 17 19C17 22.88 20.12 26 24 26C27.88 26 31 22.88 31 19C31 15.12 27.88 12 24 12ZM24 22C23.2044 22 22.4413 21.6839 21.8787 21.1213C21.3161 20.5587 21 19.7956 21 19C21 18.2044 21.3161 17.4413 21.8787 16.8787C22.4413 16.3161 23.2044 16 24 16C24.7956 16 25.5587 16.3161 26.1213 16.8787C26.6839 17.4413 27 18.2044 27 19C27 19.7956 26.6839 20.5587 26.1213 21.1213C25.5587 21.6839 24.7956 22 24 22Z" fill="black" />
          </svg>

        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>Lorem and Ipsum</h3>
          <p class="box-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button-group">
          <a class="secondary-btn" href="#">See all</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card-box">
        <div class="icons">
          <svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M24 4C21.3736 4 18.7728 4.51732 16.3463 5.52241C13.9198 6.5275 11.715 8.00069 9.85786 9.85786C6.10714 13.6086 4 18.6957 4 24C4 29.3043 6.10714 34.3914 9.85786 38.1421C11.715 39.9993 13.9198 41.4725 16.3463 42.4776C18.7728 43.4827 21.3736 44 24 44C29.3043 44 34.3914 41.8929 38.1421 38.1421C41.8929 34.3914 44 29.3043 44 24C44 21.3736 43.4827 18.7728 42.4776 16.3463C41.4725 13.9198 39.9993 11.715 38.1421 9.85786C36.285 8.00069 34.0802 6.5275 31.6537 5.52241C29.2272 4.51732 26.6264 4 24 4V4ZM14.14 36.56C15 34.76 20.24 33 24 33C27.76 33 33 34.76 33.86 36.56C31.0588 38.7921 27.5817 40.0051 24 40C20.28 40 16.86 38.72 14.14 36.56ZM36.72 33.66C33.86 30.18 26.92 29 24 29C21.08 29 14.14 30.18 11.28 33.66C9.15237 30.8892 7.99933 27.4934 8 24C8 15.18 15.18 8 24 8C32.82 8 40 15.18 40 24C40 27.64 38.76 31 36.72 33.66V33.66ZM24 12C20.12 12 17 15.12 17 19C17 22.88 20.12 26 24 26C27.88 26 31 22.88 31 19C31 15.12 27.88 12 24 12ZM24 22C23.2044 22 22.4413 21.6839 21.8787 21.1213C21.3161 20.5587 21 19.7956 21 19C21 18.2044 21.3161 17.4413 21.8787 16.8787C22.4413 16.3161 23.2044 16 24 16C24.7956 16 25.5587 16.3161 26.1213 16.8787C26.6839 17.4413 27 18.2044 27 19C27 19.7956 26.6839 20.5587 26.1213 21.1213C25.5587 21.6839 24.7956 22 24 22Z" fill="black" />
          </svg>

        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>Lorem and Ipsum</h3>
          <p class="box-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button-group">
          <a class="secondary-btn" href="#">See all</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
```

Comment: It's best if questions contain one question rather than 3. It's also not clear why media queries are a problem, considering they're already present. It's also not clear at what specific resolutions you're having issues (tablet and mobile are vague).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I want the grids to work in a way that the flexboxes flow in the next row without breaking. Updated it with one question only.

Comment: I'm not sure how your comment relates to mine, especially the last sentence of my comment. I read that part of your original question and it's good to want things, but not always practical. The problem at lower resolutions is that you have very generous padding on the `.card-box` rule.